# SEO results from a single blog vs multiple blogs

Tags: seo, blogs, blogger, traffic

Consider a website with multiple sections, each with a different set of data/features. Now to promote the website through blogging which of the following method is better and how is it better than the other:

1. A single blog is created which has multiple categories and each category corresponds to one section of the website. In this way each and every section of the website is covered and you can manage all the stuff in just one blog.
2. Separate blogs are created for each section of the website. The content of each blog is unique and you can promote each section of the website more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If the sections on your website cater to each other e.g surround a common theme I would only create separate blogs if you have enough content to fill them up in a quality way.
Gaining readers, backlinks and reputation as a site will be much easier if you can focus on one blog.

If the content on your webpage is very diverse I would go for separate blogs. That way its easier for your readers and searchengines to grasp your theme.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, as far as the content is concerned, it does vary from each other. And we have lots of content which is updated on daily basis. The portal is an infotainment portal which provides information on various subjects.

Comment: To give an example were i would decide to branch out to different sites. The mainpage is sport related, hiking,running,biking,fishing,climbing,scuba, horses. From this list  conclude what stands apart enough to get a separate site. e.g scuba | horses | climbing |fishing| hiking,biking,running. BUT if you have enough content to create a full featured blog for every one of these themes go for separate blogs. Thats also something that can be done later. That way you see what people are interested in and works in seo terms.

Comment: That's very helpful Thomas. You might wanna see this portal as an example of what kind of portal I am talking about and is it really worth creating multiple blogs or not. http://www.fun2z.com

Comment: Had a peek at the site: Would suggest a technology branch with the mobile and SMS stuff and the seo stuff sprinkeled in, a girls Page and a celebrity news / entertainment branch. That would leave you with 3-4 blogs. btw your design is very techie, for the girls section i would have imagined something more fancy.

Comment: yeah may be you are right.. Will definitely consider making it a bit fancy :) Thanks a lot for your time and nice suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

If your website has multiple industries and each one is serving many services, then separate blogs for each industry and categorize them with your industry related services.

If your website is focusing only on one industry then simply make a single blog and categorize them with different services. It will also help the users to read stuff related to your different services from a single platform.

Answer (score 0):

1. separate blogs used only for first positions using url more work and time required if multiple blogs
2. but single all in one blog have always success and high view and earnings and seo for single blog is also easy and permanent